# Ignore Table columns in JQuery visualize

Tags: jquery, charts, visualize

I'm trying to get some charts from tables using Jquery Visualize from here : http://filamentgroup.com/lab/update_to_jquery_visualize_accessible_charts_with_html5_from_designing_with/

For some reason, I can't get it to display the chart legend/key which categories are in the first column, it just includes the first column values in the graph, which doesn't display anything as they're text (Team Names) and the rest of the tables is those teams sales stats.

Is there an option or anything to make it recognize the first column as series names?

Answer (score 4):

Hopefully you've found the answer already, but for future searchers, the column which contains your series names should be a `<th>` tag with `scope='row'`. The visualize function looks for this type of tag when it's building the chart to know what the series names are and, failing that, makes them all data sets.